# Pandas Dataframe name of the column with maximum value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Watching this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/P_q0tkYqvSk?t=830

In the video, the below code returns a series with names of the columns with a maximum value per row. What happens when I run the code is I get the index location but i am not sure how to translate it to be column name.

drinks.column.values might be used i need a little help

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
drinks = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pandas-videos/master/data/drinks.csv')
drinks.head()
drinks.loc[:,'beer_servings':'wine_servings'].apply(np.argmax,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `idxmax()`:

```
drinks.loc[:,'beer_servings':'wine_servings'].idxmax(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lambda` function like

```py
drinks.loc[:,'beer_servings':'wine_servings'].apply(lambda x: drinks.columns[x.argmax()], axis=1)
0              country
1        beer_servings
2              country
3      spirit_servings
4              country
            ...
188            country
189            country
190            country
191            country
192            country
Length: 193, dtype: object
>>>
```